# Build containers according to numbers in a list of integer

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Suppose I have a list of int : `List<int> numberofcontainers = [2, 7, 1]`

Now I want to build containers according to the number at a particular index. if 2 then build 2 containers and if 7 build 7 containers and so on.

dummy layout:

```
 Column(
     children: [
 Row(
     children: [
       2 containers
   ],
),
 Row(
     children: [
       7 containers
     ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Did my answer not solve your question?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NestedContainers extends StatelessWidget {
 final List<int> numberofcontainers = [2, 7, 1];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('NestedContainers StackOverFlow'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: numberofcontainers.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return SizedBox(
                  width: 1000,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 200,
                        height: 40,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: numberofcontainers[index],
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index2) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Container(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                child: Text(
                                  '${index2 + 1}',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```